# TypeScript: Generic that is any plain object

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

> **edit** Here is my actual code to explain the issue:
>
> https://gist.github.com/LukasBombach/7bf255392074509147a250b448388518

With TypeScript I want to specify a generic that is any data structure of a plain object

```
class MyClass<T extends {}> {
  public vars: T;

  constructor() {
    this.vars = {};
  }
}
```

so I can do

```
interface MyType {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
}

new MyClass<MyType>()
```

or

```
interface MyType {
  baz: string;
  boo: {
    bam: Function;
    bix: number;
  };
}

new MyClass<MyType>()
```

My proposed implementation up there does not work though, I am getting the error:

```
class MyClass<T extends {}> {
  public vars: T;

  constructor() {
    this.vars = {};
    //   ^^^^
  }
}
```

> ```
> Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'T'.
>   '{}' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{}'.ts(2322)
> ```

Comment: T extends {}, but {} doesn't necessarily extend T. So assigning {} to a variable of type T is indeed incorrect. Suppose that you create a suclass MyClassOfCar which extends MyClass<Car>. {} is not a Car, is it?

Comment: JB answered this, you can't do it because it doesn't make logical sense. Looking at your real code I don't think using a type argument really makes sense for the base parser class. It doesn't enforce the type in any way, it might as well return `any` and a higher level class can enforce the type.

Answer (score 1):

Define the type for `vars` as a `Partial<T>`

```
class MyClass<T> {
  public vars: Partial<T>;

  constructor() {
    this.vars = {};
  }
}
```

This tells TypeScript that all of the properties are *optional*.

```
const x = new MyClass<MyType>();

console.log(x.vars.foo); // prints "undefined" but there is no TS error
console.log(x.vars.thing); // prints "undefined" but TS error for unknown property.
```

https://netbasal.com/getting-to-know-the-partial-type-in-typescript-ecfcfbc87cb6

Once a type is *partial* it is always *partial*. You'll get a warning doing the following.

```
const x: Partial<FooBar> = {};
const y: FooBar = x; // TS error, because x is partial.
```

You can force the assignment by casting.

```
const y: FooBar = x as FooBar;
```

The thing here is that you've already defined the variable as *partial*. So it's *true* that you'll never know the if it's truly populated with values.

You can use a run-time type verifier to check:

```
export function isMyType(value: any): value is MyType {
   return typeof value['foot'] === 'string'
          && typeof value['bar'] === 'number';
}

const x: Partial<MyType> = {};

if(isMyType(x)) {
    const y: MyType = x; // there is no TS, because of the isMyType check
}
```

I forget what the `is` operator in TypeScript is called, but when used inside a condition block the *type* for the checked variable is changed. So TypeScript won't complain about it.

It also gives you a change to throw a run-time error if the value is not what you think it should be.

Comment: hey thanks, I tried this, there is still a problem with this. See my class using the generic is called `Parser` it as a method returning the vars with `: Partial<T>`. Now when I call it like this:

`parse(data: DataView): ParseResult {
    return new Parser<ParseResult>(data)
      .char("state")
      .char("substate")
      .vars();
  }` 

I get the error `Property 'state' is optional in type 'Partial<ParseResult>' but required in type 'ParseResult'.` `state` is a required `string` in `ParseResult`

Comment: @Lukas yeah, I should have added a warning. Once a type is marked partial it is always partial. You can't assign it to the non-partial version. TypeScript has no way of knowing if the run-time has all the properties. I'll update my answer, but working with partials can be tricky.

Comment: See this example: https://gist.github.com/LukasBombach/7bf255392074509147a250b448388518

Answer (score 0):

The error is perfectly logical.

Using your first example of `MyType`, this is the equivalent `MyClass` without the generic:

```ts
interface MyType {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
}

class MyClass {
  public vars: MyType;

  constructor() {
    this.vars = {};
  }
}
```

Since `vars` now must have `foo` and `bar` members, assigning `vars = {}` is not allowed.

Comment: But I want the vars to be of any type that can be passed on to the class using generics. Using MyType directly defeats the purpose.

Comment: @Lukas My example was meant to illustrate the intermediate stage generated by the compiler, I'm not suggesting you should hardcode `MyType` into `MyClass`. But I do have to ask, what are you achieving with a generic here that you can't by just using `any`?

Comment: I want to be able to define the return value of a method by calling the class with a generic

Comment: Wait I will add the real example as a gist

Comment: here you can see my actual example: https://gist.github.com/LukasBombach/7bf255392074509147a250b448388518

Answer (score 0):

I think this might solve it

```
class MyClass<T extends {[key:string]: any}> {
  public vars: T;

  constructor() {
    this.vars = {};
  }
}
```

Eg:

```
interface MyType {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
}
let test = new MyClass<MyType>();
```

On test you will be able to find vars which will be of type MyType and on test.vars you can see foo and bar property available